# Give CSS :after content a class

Tags: css

I'm just wondering if it is possible to assign a CSS class to the content added by an :after pseudoelement. Something like this:

```
span:after {
  content: "after!"
  class: red
}
```

I know you can specify several style attributes like font-size and so on, so I could imagine applying a class should be possible, too.

Acutally, I'm trying to append a glyphicon via bootstrap CSS this way. But a simple

```
span:after {
  class: icon-wrench
}
```

didn't do it.

Comment: Using some CSS preprocessors (SASS or LESS) this would be a mixin use case

Comment: yes, but .icon-wrench has been defined in bootstrap.css. I cannot make a mixin out of it in my custom.sass file, can I?

Comment: in your sass file you could create a mixin with that specific rule (defined again, ugly!) and then include it

Comment: Yes, but that's what I don't want to do. If I redefine the class, I can also simply redefine it in the :after block directly without using any mixin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pseudo-elements can't have classes. You can only apply individual style rules to them directly. There isn't a way to copy styles from a real element of a certain class to its pseudo-element either, unless you specifically select it, something like `span.icon-wrench:after`.